# How to add ticks around a field when using the map function with params for rust?

Tags: rust

I need to add ticks around the table name in a MySQL query in Rust but the map function doesn't process what's between the ticks.

What I need is:

```
conn.exec_batch("INSERT INTO `:table_name` ...",
    items.iter().map(|item| params! {
        "table_name" => table_name,
```

However the MySQL error reports that the table name is just a question mark. The function works if I manually insert the table name so I know the rest of the function is working correctly.

Comment: How about using format for the SQL-string, i.e. conn.exec_batch( format!("INSERT INTO `{}`", table_name), items.iter()...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. That worked and was better for my use case.

Comment: Be warned, using `format!()` for SQL statements is how SQL injection vulnerabilities happen. If you are in full control of `table_name` then ok, but I suggest you don't let it become a habit.

Comment: Is that params macro from a crate?

Comment: MySQL crate. https://docs.rs/mysql/12.0.4/mysql/macro.params.html